# NumPy Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am working on an Image Convolution code using numpy:

```
def CG(A, b, x, imax=10, epsilon = 0.01):
    steps=np.asarray(x)
    i = 0
    r = b - A * x
    d = r.copy()
    delta_new = r.T * r
    delta_0 = delta_new
    while i < imax and delta_new > epsilon**2 * delta_0:
        q = A * d
        alpha = float(delta_new / (d.T * q))
        x = x + alpha * d
        if i%50 == 0:
            r = b - A * x
        else:
            r = r - alpha * q
        delta_old = delta_new
        delta_new = r.T * r
        beta = float(delta_new / delta_old)
        d = r + beta * d
        i = i + 1
        steps = np.append(steps, np.asarray(x), axis=1)
    return steps
```

I get the below error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

on line `while i < imax and delta_new > epsilon**2 * delta_0:`

Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like `delta_new` and `delta_0` are Numpy arrays, and Numpy doesn't know how to compare them.

As an example, imagine if you took two random Numpy arrays and tried to compare them:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 3, 5])
>>> b = np.array([5, 3, 1])
>>> print(a<b)
array([True, False, False])
>>> bool(a<b)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

You have to basically "pick" how to collapse the comparisons of all of the values across all of your arrays down to a single bool.

```
>>> (a<b).any()
True

>>> (a<b).all()
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Effectively you have a matrix `delta_new` which is being compared to another matrix `epsilon**2 * delta_0` which produces multiple truth values.

With multiple truth values, there is not definitive yes or no.

So that condition can use `.all` (and for each element) or `.any` (or for each element) to resolve this multiplicity.

Answer (score 1):

`delta_new` is a matrix.  Linear arithmetic comparison operations are not defined for matrices.  You tried to compare a matrix of values to another matrix of values with a simple scalar comparison.  Python doesn't know how to give you a single T/F result from this.

I suspect that you want some scalar property on the matrices, such as determinant.

Comment: Ahh .. that makes sense. I am a freaking idiot !! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

this also occurs for sparse matrices e.g.: `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

workaround is to add `todense()`