# If statement comparing numpy array raised ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

I have two arrays. Both are 1D. However, I am getting the following Value Error. Below is what I tried.

```
R=np.arange(30,50,1)
T=np.arange(70,90,1)

H=[]

if (T > 8) and (R>10): 
   H.append(0.5 * (T + 61. + (T - 68.) * 1.2 + R * 0.094))
else:
   H.append(0 * 2)
```

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Please include `T` and `R` so that your problem is reproducible

Comment: @7koFnMiP . I added them, thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this? [NumPy Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191677/numpy-error-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 0):

Python struggled to compare the values in the lists `T` to number. 
The error is raised on `T > 8`.

***For Lists***

1. Use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to check if all items in the list are above value:

```
all(x > value for x in list)
```

3. Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check if any item in the list are above value:

```
any(x > value for x in list)
```

***For NumPy Array***

1. When having `NumPy` array, this can be shortened to:

```
T = np.array([1,2,3])
all(T > 8)
```

***Fix***

Fix to `all`:

```
H=[]

import numpy as np

T = np.array([30,34,56])
R = np.array([29,500,43])

if all(T > 8) and all(R > 10):
    H.append(0.5 * (T + 61. + (T - 68.) * 1.2 + R * 0.094))
else:
    H.append(0 * 2)
```

Comment: with numpy this can be shortened to just `(T > 8).all()`, etc.

Comment: I checked both T and R using `all(T > 80 for T in T)` and `all (T > 80 for T in T)`. I got `False` for both cases.

Comment: Then what you are looking for might by `.any()`

Comment: @Chane use: `all(T > 8) and all(R > 10)` to check all values or `any(T > 8) and any(R > 10)` to check if any of the values is above threshold

Answer (score 0):

Like the above answer states, you can use all or any.
The fix using any is:

```
if any(t > value for t in T) and any(h > value for h in H):
   H.append(0.5 * (T + 61. + (T - 68.) * 1.2 + R * 0.094))
else:
   H.append(0 * 2)
```

The python interpreter needs 1 value at a time so that it can compare.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that.

```py
import numpy as np
R=np.arange(30,50,1)
T=np.arange(70,90,1)

H=[]

if (T > 8).all() and (R>10).all():
   H.append(0.5 * (T + 61. + (T - 68.) * 1.2 + R * 0.094))
else:
   H.append(0 * 2)

print(H)
```

Here is an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362238/the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous-in-python/63364067#63364067).

If you really just want to know if atleast one  element falls under the condition you should use `any()`.